# Can I connect the frame ground on a PSU to the 'ground/earth' on a UK plug?

Tags: power-supply, ground, wiring

I have a PSU which has 'FG' (Frame ground), is this just the ground which I would attach to the ground pin of the UK plug?

Image of the Live, Neutral & FG : [image: https://gyazo.com/72cafecf482b7a2bad8b7aea14bc431e]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it definitely is the ground pin.

Devices which have ground pin must be connected to grounded outlet.